# xmlstarlet add element with namespace and attributes

Tags: xmlstarlet

I'm trying to add a node with a namespace and an attribute to an xml, but it fails if I try to do it as multiple commands in one execution of xmlstarlet:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<levela xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <levelb>
  </levelb>
</levela>
```

`xmlstarlet ed -L -s /levela/levelb -t elem -n xi:input -i //xi:input -t attr -n "href" -v "aHref" file.xml`

I'm trying to get:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<levela xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <levelb>
     <xi:input href="aHref"/>
  </levelb>
</levela>
```

But the attribute isn't added. So I get:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<levela xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <levelb>
     <xi:input/>
  </levelb>
</levela>
```

It works if I run it as two executions like this:

`xmlstarlet ed -L -s /levela/levelb -t elem -n xi:input file.xml`

`xmlstarlet ed -L -i //xi:input -t attr -n "href" -v "aHref" file.xml`

It also works if I add a tag without a namespace e.g:

`xmlstarlet ed -L -s /levela/levelb -t elem -n levelc -i //levelc -t attr -n "href" -v "aHref" file.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<levela xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <levelb>
     <levelc href="aHref"/>
  </levelb>
</levela>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't it work with the namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```sh
xmlstarlet edit \
  -s '/levela/levelb' -t elem -n 'xi:input' \
  -s '$prev' -t attr -n 'href' -v 'aHref' \
file.xml
```

`xmlstarlet edit` code can use the convenience `$prev` (aka
`$xstar:prev`) variable to refer to the node created by the most
recent `-i (--insert)`, `-a (--append)`, or `-s (--subnode)` option.
Examples of `$prev` are given in
[doc/xmlstarlet.txt](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt) and
the source code's
[examples/ed-backref*](https://fossies.org/linux/www/xmlstarlet-1.6.1.tar.gz/).

Attributes can be added using `-i`, `-a`, or `-s`.

> What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't it work with the namespace?

**Update** 2022-04-15
The `-i '//xi:input' …` syntax you use is perfectly logical. As your
own 2 alternative commands suggest it's the namespace `xi` that
triggers the omission and there's a hint in the `edInsert` function in
the source code's
[src/xml_edit.c](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/src/xml_edit.c)
where it says `NULL /* TODO: NS */`.
When you've worked with `xmlstarlet` for some
time you come to accept its limitations (or not); in this case the
`$prev` back reference is useful. I wouldn't expect that `TODO` to
go away anytime soon.
(**end** update)

Well, I think `xmlstarlet edit` looks upon node naming as a user
responsibility, as the following example suggests,

```sh
printf '<v/>' |
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
  -s '*' -t elem -n 'undeclared:qname' -v 'x' \
  -s '*' -t elem -n '!--' -v ' wotsinaname ' \
  -s '$prev' -t attr -n ' "" ' -v '' \
  -s '*' -t elem -n ' <&> ' -v 'harrumph!'
```

the output of which is clearly not XML:

```
<v>
  <undeclared:qname>x</undeclared:qname>
  <!--  "" =""> wotsinaname </!-->
  < <&> >harrumph!</ <&> >
</v>
```

---

If you want to indent the new element, for example:

```sh
xmlstarlet edit \
  -s '/levela/levelb' -t elem -n 'xi:input' \
  --var newnd '$prev' \
  -s '$prev' -t attr -n 'href' -v 'aHref' \
  -a '$newnd' -t text -n ignored -v '' \
  -u '$prev' -x '(//text())[1][normalize-space()=""]' \
file.xml
```

The `-x` XPath expression grabs the first text node provided it
contains nothing but whitespace, i.e. the first child node of `levela`.
The `--var name xpath` option to define an `xmlstarlet edit`
variable is mentioned in
[doc/xmlstarlet.txt](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt)
but not in the user's guide.

I used `xmlstarlet` version 1.6.1.

Comment: Thank you! Nice solution, I had completely missed back-references. 
  
Though I still don't quite understand why an xpath that works perfectly on the generated XML doesn't work if I run it as a second command. If you can elaborate it would be appreciated. Regardless I accepted your answer since it solves the problem of addressing the new node.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't insert an attribute and attribute value into a namespaced node... Maybe someone smarter can figure out something else, but the only way I could get around that, at least in this case, is this:

```
 xmlstarlet ed -N xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" --subnode "//levela/levelb" \
 --type elem -n "xi:input" --insert  "//levela/levelb/*"  --type attr --name "href"\
 --value "aHref" file.xml
```

Comment: Interesting, at least you can get the node with xpath. But I do feel it's cheating a bit updating all nodes at the level even if it works for my example  =)