# Insert a line xml file by using XMLStart

Tags: linux, xml, shell, xmlstarlet

Hi I've the following file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="" xmlns:uap="" IgnorableNamespaces="">
  <Identity Name="xxxxxxxxxx" Publisher="CN=$username$" Version="xxxx"/>
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="xxxxxxxxxxx" PhonePublisherId=""/>
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>xxxxxxxxxx</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>xxxxxxxx</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>images\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
    <Description>A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.</Description>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily MaxVersionTested="" MinVersion="" Name="Windows.Universal"/>
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="" StartPage="">
      </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient"/>
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam"/>
    <DeviceCapability Name="location"/>
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

I wanted to insert  under the Capabilities element. So, the output should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="" xmlns:uap="" IgnorableNamespaces="">
  <Identity Name="xxxxxxxxxx" Publisher="CN=$username$" Version="xxxx"/>
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="xxxxxxxxxxx" PhonePublisherId=""/>
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>xxxxxxxxxx</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>xxxxxxxx</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>images\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
    <Description>A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.</Description>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily MaxVersionTested="" MinVersion="" Name="Windows.Universal"/>
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="" StartPage="">
      </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient"/>
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer"/>
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam"/>
    <DeviceCapability Name="location"/>
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

To achieve the above I'm using XMLStarlet as below.

```
xmlstarlet ed \
  -a '/Package/Capabilities' -t elem -n Capability \
  -i '/Package/Capabilities/Capability' -t attr -n Name -v privateNetworkClientServer \
<inputfile >outputfile
```

The output I'm getting is the same without any modifications. Am I doing anything silly.

Answer (score 0):

If I strip out all the namespace-related stuff, then

```bash
xmlstarlet ed \
    -a '/Package/Capabilities/Capability[last()]' -t elem -n 'Capability' \
    -a '/Package/Capabilities/Capability[last()]' -t attr -n Name -v privateNetworkClientServer \
  inputfile.no_namespace
```

adds the node after the last Capability:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package IgnorableNamespaces="">
  ...
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient"/>
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer"/>
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam"/>
    <DeviceCapability Name="location"/>
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

However, with your given XML, xmlstarlet spits out errors:

```
$ xmlstarlet ... inputfile
inputfile:2.93: xmlns:mp: Empty XML namespace is not allowed
ns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp=""
                                                                               ^
inputfile:2.106: xmlns:uap: Empty XML namespace is not allowed
hemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="" xmlns:uap=""
                                                                               ^
inputfile:4.69: Namespace prefix mp on PhoneIdentity is not defined
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="xxxxxxxxxxx" PhonePublisherId=""/>
                                                                    ^
[original XML here]
```

You're dealing with invalid XML, and xmlstarlet is not very forgiving.

Comment: actually, its a package.windows10.appxmanifest file. Need to add one capability for building a windows application. So, I need to add that. But I'm not sure even with above it gives the same input file. Maybe it doesn't work with non xml files ?

Comment: Whatever the source of the file, xmlstarlet cannot handle the `xmlns:mp=""` and `xmlns:uap=""` attributes of Package. `xmllint` spits out the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

The target node exists in the default namespace so adjust your XPath expression:

```sh
xmlstarlet edit \
  -a '/_:Package/_:Capabilities/_:Capability[last()]' -t elem -n 'Capability' \
  -s '$prev' -t attr -n Name -v 'privateNetworkClientServer' \
file.xml
```

- using the [_ (underscore)](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139531936) shortcut
  since the default namespace is declared in the root element
  (option [`--doc-namespace`](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139669232) being in effect)
- the `$prev` (aka `$xstar:prev`) variable refers to the node
  created by the most recent `-i (--insert)`, `-a (--append)`, or
  `-s (--subnode)`; examples of `$prev` are given in
  [doc/xmlstarlet.txt](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet.txt).

Due to a bug in `xmlstarlet edit`
(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71876929/14403369))
the `$prev` back reference is required when referencing a
newly created element which is not in the null namespace.

Since `xmlstarlet edit` (unlike `xmlstarlet select`) isn't an XSLT
processor it'll accept stuff -- such as `xmlns:mp=""` -- XSLT processors
will reject as non-XML.